# Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement'

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i'm trying to make my own "website checker" for specific needs and i'm having problem accessing the iFrame..

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://
>   checker.xcore.co.il" from accessing a frame with origin "http://
>   xcore.co.il". The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to
>   "checker.xcore.co.il", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must
>   set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.

I must do this using iFrame because i need to access classes CSS.
[Click on this link](http://checker.xcore.co.il/), load the website and then click "fontSizeErrors" on the right
and then you can see the error in the console log.

How can i pass this please?? I couldn't find anything helpful on Google..

Thanks!

Comment: Its called the html same origin policy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. Even http://a.example.com cannot access data from http://b.example.com do to security reasons.

Comment: you can't bypass it unless you have access to both domains and can set `document.domain` to match in both

Comment: run your script on the actual page via tampermonkey or greasmonkey instead of your own page with an iframe.

Comment: How people make website checkers such as http://wave.webaim.org/ ? There must be a way i can pull each class's CSS

Answer (score 6):

That's a normal security measure used by all the browsers. You **can't** access elements or frames that have a different origin, that would be a huge security flaw. Hence, the browser blocks all the scripts that try to do that kind of stuff. To perform any action inside a frame its content must have the same origin.

**For further information [take look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame/25098153#25098153) of mine.**

Comment: How people make website checkers such as http://wave.webaim.org/ ? There must be a way i can pull each class's CSS

Comment: @user3298188 I guess they just make some XMLHttpRequests and inspect the content, but I don't know the logic behind it, sorry

Comment: once you have language which is capable of parsing URL page as string, you can do any magic you want ;)

Comment: How can this possibly be a security flaw?? The DOM I load in my browser, I should be able to handle it whichever way I want...

Comment: @Dalibor no, you shouldn't. If this was possible then *anyone* could modify and inject scripts inside frames of different sites, doing whatever they want. This would be a **huge security flaw**. To make a silly example, just think about a malicious site loading an hidden iframe containing the web page of your bank: you are already logged in because you use it often, and the malicious site would be able to access all of your data. This would be very, very dangerous.

Comment: You're right. The moment I posted my response, I thought of those phising example. Makes sense, thanks.  However, that issue makes my life complicated in implementing remote iframes in cordova/ionic app...