# accessing span in iframe through javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to access the **yellow highlighted span tag value** give in the image below:

[image]

I tried the following in chrome console but it gives `undefined` value as follows:

[image]

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this? How do I get the span value?

Comment: the id is **id_frame** and not **frameID** ????

Comment: actually `id_frame` is a temporary id added by me, originally iframe does not have any id, I tried with `id_frame` too in console but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$('#id_frame').contents().find('#queuedBetTotal').text();
```

You should also know that if the iframe source is pointing to a different domain, due to security reasons, you will not be able to access the contents of this iframe in javascript.

Comment: please check my edited question, actually the iFrame does not have any id.

Comment: @z22: is it from cross domain??

Comment: yes it's pointing to a different domain, and as you said it is giving security error: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame. How do I access this?

Comment: You don't need an ID to do that, if it is the only iframe or the first one, you can do $('iframe')

Comment: @z22: i am not sure whether this would work but you can give it a try http://stackoverflow.com/a/28273086/1719752

Comment: @MilindAnantwar- thanks for the link, I found that a subset of my current domain`("https://www.somesite.com/ticketpage.html")` checks for the parent origin`(""https://www.somesite.com"")` and hence it throws the error. Trying to solve this now, let me know if you have any idea for this issue. Thanks again

Comment: have you tried setting the document  domain to the domain of iframe server?? `document.domain = 'somesite.com'`

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329519/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-contentdocument-property-from-html. As it says I can't access the elements of iframe with another domain. How do I solve this now? As I don't have access to the website script. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

$('iframe').contents().find('#queuedBetTotal').html();
if you don't have id means you can use the tag name.