# External authentication doesn't work in Datazen

Tags: datazen-server

I set the authentication in control panel as below:
[image: externalauthentication]

and i call the viewer by this code:

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://192.168.17.31/viewer',
        headers: {'thisistheheadername':'thisistheheadername'},
        type : 'GET'
       });
```

but still request redirects to login page:

http://192.168.17.31/viewer/login

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do. I've never seen AJAX used with Datazen like this, although I suppose I can understand how it might work. Of course, it won't be secure, because the browser could always indicate who the user should be--there's no checking.

The top chart in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35142103/1270504) might help you. But beyond that, what tells you it's sending to the login page? Where are you trying to display the results?

The two things I would check on outside of those, though, are:

1. Your header is not correct, unless you've got a user named "thisistheheadername" as well. You should be passing a username through that value. I don't recall specifically, but it could send you to the login page if it doesn't recognize the username.
2. Are you sure external authentication is enabled? I would check in the "Configuration" section on the server to ensure it isn't still "default." The core service must be stopped before changes are persisted.