# Edit iframe content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

i am trying to edit content from iframe using jquery but nothing really seems to happen. Can anyone explain why please?

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<iframe src="//api.jquery.com/" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo"></iframe>

    <script>
    $( "#frameDemo" ).contents().find( ".page-title" ).text('My html');
    </script>
```

Comment: You can't because of security. What if I could load a page and run some javascript on it. Would be messed up right?

Comment: Is it possible then to iframe some website to my website and edit certain parts?

Comment: Pleas see this answer. You can't http://stackoverflow.com/a/26329643/4194436

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329519/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-read-the-contentdocument-property-from-html)

Comment: What about this post saying that contents() can manipulate parts of an iframe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924936/change-html-of-an-iframe-with-jquery

Comment: That is from 4 years ago, if you looked at your console you will see the error and it also tells you why you can't access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access or manipulate content from another domain in this way. This is blocked by something called the same-origin policy.

As [the MDN page on this subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) states, the same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a critical security mechanism for isolating potentially malicious scripts.

It is however possible to manipulate the HTML of an iframe that is on the same domain. You'd do that like this:

```
$("#frameid").contents().find("div").html('My html');
```

See here: [Change HTML of an iFrame with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924936/change-html-of-an-iframe-with-jquery)